# Imagemagick Keep File Names & Add Prefixes

Tags: cmd, imagemagick, rename, clone, batch-rename

I have a script that resizes all images from a source directory into a destination directory, but I need to keep the original filenames and add "100-", "200-" and "400-" to the beginning of the file names.

Here is what I have currently:

magick C:\Users\joe\Desktop\Source*.jpg ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 400x400 +write C:/Users/joe/Desktop/Destination/400.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 200x200 +write C:/Users/joe/Desktop/Destination/200.jpg ) ^
( -clone 0--1 -resize 100x100 +write C:/Users/joe/Desktop/Destination/100.jpg ) ^
null:

This works, but it doesn't keep the original file names it just does "400-1.jpg", "400-2.jpg", "400-3.jpg" and so on.

How would I get it to maintain the file names and add these on to the start of the name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I'll let you figure out how to replace things in your own incantation:

```
convert -verbose /tmp/*.png -set filename:out "%[directory]/400-%[basename]" "%[filename:out].jpg"
```

You can do several variations around this depending on the output directory (explicit, from the input image, or the working directory). The final output substitution can only have a single escape, which is why the name is constructed when setting `filename:out`.

See [this](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes) for the gory details.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply - so I would be able to only do this within one directory and one prefix?

I would need it to be either three different prefixes based on the file resizing, or three different directories one containing each size of file.

Comment: I have seen since writing  the answer that the escape could use the width (`%w`) of the image, so you would not need to hard-code it in the name.